# Update RecyclerView outside of class

Tags: c#, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

I have the following code example from [cforbeginners](http://cforbeginners.com/XamarinProjects.html) and am trying to update an existing array and then use that array to update the `RecyclerView` from a separate class. Specifically I am trying to update from a background service. I have been trying to find a working example of this.

Main Activity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RecyclerViewTutorial
{
[Activity(Label = "RecyclerViewTutorial", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private MyList mEmails;


protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
base.OnCreate(bundle);

// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
mRecyclerView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
mEmails = new MyList();
mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna hang out?", Message = "I'll be around tomorrow!!" });
mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna hang out?", Message = "I'll be around tomorrow!!" });
mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna hang out?", Message = "I'll be around tomorrow!!" });
mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna hang out?", Message = "I'll be around tomorrow!!" });


//Create our layout manager
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, mRecyclerView);
mEmails.Adapter = mAdapter;
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);


}

public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar, menu);
return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
switch(item.ItemId)
{
case Resource.Id.add:
//Add button clicked
mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "New Name", Subject = "New Subject", Message = "New Message" });
return true;

case Resource.Id.discard:
//Discard button clicked
mEmails.Remove(mEmails.Count - 1);
return true;
}
return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

public class MyList
{
private List mItems;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

public MyList()
{
mItems = new List();
}

public RecyclerView.Adapter Adapter
{
get { return mAdapter; }
set { mAdapter = value; }
}

public void Add(T item)
{
mItems.Add(item);

if (Adapter != null)
{
Adapter.NotifyItemInserted(0);
}

}

public void Remove (int position)
{
mItems.RemoveAt(position);

if (Adapter != null)
{
Adapter.NotifyItemRemoved(0);
}
}

public T this[int index]
{
get { return mItems[index]; }
set { mItems[index] = value; }
}

public int Count
{
get { return mItems.Count; }
}

}

public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
private MyList mEmails;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public RecyclerAdapter(MyList emails, RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
mEmails = emails;
mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
}

public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
public View mMainView { get; set; }
public TextView mName { get; set; }
public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

public MyView (View view) : base(view)
{
mMainView = view;
}
}

public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);

TextView txtName = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtName);
TextView txtSubject = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtSubject);
TextView txtMessage = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtMessage);

MyView view = new MyView(row) { mName = txtName, mSubject = txtSubject, mMessage = txtMessage };
return view;
}

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
MyView myHolder = holder as MyView;
int indexPosition = (mEmails.Count - 1) - position;
myHolder.mMainView.Click += mMainView_Click;
myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[indexPosition].Name;
myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[indexPosition].Subject;
myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[indexPosition].Message;
}

void mMainView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int position = mRecyclerView.GetChildPosition((View)sender);
int indexPosition = (mEmails.Count - 1) - position;
Console.WriteLine(mEmails[indexPosition].Name);
}

public override int ItemCount
{
get { return mEmails.Count; }
}
}
}
```

Email.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace RecyclerViewTutorial
{
public class Email
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Message { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; }
public bool Favorite { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here instead of a 3rd party website.

Comment: Alright! Sorry.